# How to show a div based on on area coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a problem, i am trying to assign a div to a specific area coordinate on click and display it. But is not working.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-group a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('.' + this.id).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdowntest-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map"> 
    <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" 
    coords="198,368,142,337" href="#section-1" />
</map>

<img alt="Picture1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/680x466/444444/DDDDDD?text=Placeholder"
    width="680" height="466" usemap="map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />`

<div class="dropdowntest-content hide section-1">
  <p>Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you showing it? It has the `.hide` class. And also `display: none;`.

Comment: I am showing on on the picture.... the display:none; is set at the beginning so it's not showed before the click

Comment: Then where is your click event? And the button that's shows it? They are missing in your fiddle.

Comment: This is the click even on the javascript that i have posted at the top $('.list-group a').on('click', function(e) {

Comment: But the click event there hides it with `.hide()`

Comment: oh okay...so what's your possible solution to this?

Comment: Do you want to click on the map to move the div there or do you want to click on the div and move it to the map? Because the area is invisible right now and hard to click.

Comment: @Deathshadow so what i want to do is to click on that coordinate and display the information of that area clicked, that's all. so if they click on another cordinate, the information of that coordinate will be dsiplayed/pop up

Comment: so the div should be displayed at exactly the coordinates which the area is right?

Comment: @Deathshadow yes... so click and display the information in the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple errors in your code.

The first is the `img` tag wasn't using the map because it was missing `#` in the `use-map: #map`.

You were also unnecessarily hiding the `div` on click. And you were referencing an `a` tag that didn't exist.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.list-group area').on('click', function(e) {

    $('.' + this.id).toggleClass('show');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdowntest-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

area {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map"> 
    <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" 
    coords="0,0,200,200" />
</map>

<img alt="Picture1" src="https://placehold.it/680x466" height="466" width="680" usemap="#map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />

<div class="dropdowntest-content section-1">
  <p>Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-group area').on('click', function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    var position = $(this).offset();
    $('.hide').css({
      left: position.left,
      top: position.top
     }).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdowntest-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

area,
area:link,
area:hover,
area:active,
area:focus {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img alt="Picture1" src="https://picsum.photos/466/680" height="466" width="680" usemap="#map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />

<map class="list-group" name="map"> 
    <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="poly" coords="30,100, 140,50, 290,220, 180,280" href="#section-1" />
</map>


<div class="dropdowntest-content hide section-1">
  <p>Hello
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the code to suit your solution.

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }

  .hide {
    display: none;
  }

  .dropdowntest-content {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//get element that contain the map
    var target = document.getElementById("container");
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdownmenu");

    //listen to user mouse click
    target.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

      //click mouse position relative to container
      var clk_x_pos = e.pageX - e.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
      var clk_y_pos = e.pageY - e.currentTarget.offsetTop;

      //position the drop down menu
      dropdown.setAttribute(
        "style", "top: " + clk_y_pos + "px; left: " + clk_x_pos + "px;"
      );

      //display the menu
      dropdown.setAttribute("class", "dropdowntest-content section-1");

      //prevent the default from showing
      return false;

    }, false);

    //hide the drop down menu
    target.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e){
      //hide drop down menu
      dropdown.setAttribute("class", "dropdowntest-content hide section-1");

    }, false);
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <!--Place your map here or remove the div element with id "container" and add that id to your map-->
  <div id="dropdownmenu" class="dropdowntest-content hide section-1">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```